# How to determine the Radius of convergence?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the function $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-3x)^n}{n^2}$$

I´m not realy sure where to begin and how to determine the radius of convergence. Could someone provide a nice explanation?

THX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|={}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-3x)^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}}{\frac{(-3x)^{n}}{(n)^2}}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}3|x|\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^2=3|x|$$ So if $|x|<\frac{1}{3}$ the series convergent. On the other hand if $x=\frac{1}{3}$ and $x=\frac{-1}{3}$
series converges, too. So domain of convergence is $\left[\frac{-1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}\right] $ and radius of convergence is $R=\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula

$a_n={(-3)^n\over n^2}$

${1\over R}=\lim\sup|a_n|^{1\over n}$